# Change Nicescroll position using a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click

I'm using Nicescroll plugin (3.0.0) on my webpage and the scroll is working fine.

Now the div "scrolled" by Nicescroll is very big so I would like to be able to scroll my div to a specific position by clicking on a href link.

Is it something possible with Nicescoll plugin?

The different areas in the scrollable div have specific IDs. The links are also identified and depending on the link clicked, I need to find the Y position of the corresponding area and let scroll nicescroll content to this position.

Once again bascically, the question is to know if it's possible to change position of a nicescroll content using a click on an external element.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Ben